# Edit default menu in Titanium desktop app

Tags: javascript, html, macos, titanium, appcelerator

In a Titanium OS X desktop application, is it possible to edit the default menu? You can add new menus and submenus, but you can't edit or even attach event listeners to the existing menus (help, application, edit, etc.) Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

@Brian: Yeah, I've tried that. I might be doing something wrong, though. I'm at a windows computer now and don't have the code for it, or else I'd post it. Does it use some sort of .nib file that you could replace?

Comment: once you get a chance you should post that code, I imagine once the desktop app has been built especially with the beta(http://appcel.us/lsZgu4) app store distribution one you can build in Xcode with the associated `*.xcodeproject` and remove anything from there?

Comment: I merged your accounts so you can leave comments and edit your post.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
var menu = Titanium.UI.createMenu();
menu.addItem("Quit", function(e) {
    alert("Bye!");
});
Titanium.UI.setMenu(menu);
```

That will create a menu at the top of your app window that has an option labelled "Quit," which will create an alert dialog when clicked.